# Segment above another segment

Tags: geometry

I received a task with multiple exercises and this is the only one I don't know how to solve.
So, we represent a segment in the Cartesian space by an instance of the

class Segment {
public Point3D A,B; // the coordinates of the endpoints of the segment
}

We say that a segment s1 is above another segment s2 if there is a vertical line 'l' that intersects both segments, such that the l ∩ s1 is above l ∩ s2. The following picture illustrates the situation when segment s1 is above segment s2:
[Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6cMj.png)
So I have to create a method that returns

- 0 if s1 and s1 intersect,
- 1 if s1 is above s2,
- 2 if s2 is above s1, and
- 3 otherwise.

Comment: What part of this are you struggling with? Show us your efforts.

Comment: Well, I don't know exactly how to create that sweep line, I know how to check if two segments intersect but that means they intersect at a certain point, so that is easier to compute. I've seen there exist some algorithms (Bentley Ottmann and Shamos Hoey) that handle this type of problem but I don't really find them, or maybe a code implementation that does this work (receives the coordinates of the two segments, create the vertical line and based on it, it gives me the result I was expected [0,1,2,3])

Comment: Your issue is that you are treating this as one giant problem, rather than breaking it down into pieces. Let me help you with that. Here are the things you need to be able to do: given two lines, figure out whether they intersect. Given two line segments, figure out whether they intersect (using the lines intersecting algorithm). Given two line segments, do they overlap horizontally. Given two line segments, does one have a point above the other.

Answer (score 1):

Project the segments onto the $xz$ plane. If these projected segments intersect, then either one of the segments is above the other or they intersect.